# Read a file from text and create loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file with some line example

[image]

I want to loop through each line until an create format line +1 number all words And of course, a max value must be adjustable

Like this
[image]

thanks for all the help

My code

```
  Sub homework()
        ' Dim words(5) As String
        Dim words As String() = File.ReadLines("test.txt")
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim outerLoop As Integer
        Dim innerLoop As Integer

        For i = 0 To words.Length ' i dont know how to set file line length 
            words(i) = words(i) & i + 1
        Next i

        For outerLoop = 0 To UBound(words)
            For innerLoop = 0 To UBound(words)
                If outerLoop = innerLoop Then
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(words(outerLoop) & "-" & words(innerLoop))
                End If
            Next
        Next outerLoop


    End Sub
```

after output

[image]

The problem here doesn't read all the lines in my text file, it's only processing last line.

Comment: You've explained the requirement (just about), but you haven't told us what issue exists within your current code. I assume there is a problem, or it lacks some features? Please clarify.

Comment: Your description is fairly poor, although that may be forgiven to a degree as I suspect that English is not your first language. Your example seems to be fairly clear, but then your code seems nonsensical if it is. Your example suggests that you should have one `For Each` loop and then a `For` loop inside that. I suggest that you review your question and make sure that you are providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem AND an ACCURATE example.

Comment: sorry about that add few explanation for my problem
I can't make a clear statement because I'm not entirely sure about the my code block, so I can only explain what I want.

Comment: `For i = 0 To words.Length` will give you an index out of range error. Let's say your file has 10 lines. `words.Length` will be 10 but the indexes of the lines (what you are using in your first loop) will be 0 - 9. See the problem? On the last iteration you will try to access words(10)! Oops! No such element. Index out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.ReadLines returns and IEnumerable of String whereas File.ReadAllLines returns a good old Array of String. They play by slightly different rules. Right now you will probably be more comfortable with an array.

Using a For Each loop for the outer loop is a bit easier because you don't have to worry about Index out or Range or getting UBound(words) which translates to words.GetUpperBound(0) in .net.

For the inner loop we can start with 1 and go to the value passed to you method.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    homework(3)
End Sub

Sub homework(UpperLimit As Integer)
    Dim words = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\***\Desktop\test.txt")
    For Each word In words
        For i = 1 To UpperLimit
            ListBox1.Items.Add(word & i & "-" & word & i)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The First loop is not required and modify the second loop like below:

```
Sub homework()
    ' Dim words(5) As String
    Dim words As String() = File.ReadLines("test.txt")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim outerLoop As Integer
    Dim innerLoop As Integer

    ' This Loop is not required.
    'For i = 0 To words.Length 
    '   words(i) = words(i) & i + 1
    'Next i

    For outerLoop = 0 To UBound(words)
        For innerLoop = 1 To MaxValue
            Dim str as string
            str = words(outerloop) & "-" & innerLoop
            ListBox1.Items.Add(str & "-" & str)                
        Next
    Next outerLoop
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to want a hyphen between the word and the number so the first `& "-"` should be removed.